# How do I keep a button active indefinitely after refresh/until another button is clicked?

Tags: html, button

I am attempting to code a stoplight indicating if a measurable objective is met or not using "green" and "red" as indicators for "yes" and "no" respectively.  Ideally, the stoplight would remain in either red or green status until the button is clicked again -- despite refreshing, new navigation, etc.

This is the code I am using:

```
<h2><span style="color: #000000;">Are we meeting our KPR?</span></h2>

<div><svg id="svg1" style="width: 310px;
        height: 310px;
        background-color: #333;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;"> <circle cx="155" cy="155" id="circle1" r="130" style="fill: red; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"></circle> <circle cx="155" cy="155" id="circle2" r="130" style="fill: transparent; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"></circle> </svg></div>

<p><span style="color: #FFFFFF;"></span></p>

<details open=""><summary></summary><span style="color: #FFFFFF;"> </span>

<p><span style="color: #FFFFFF;"><button id="no" onclick="circle1.style.fill='#33CC33';" type="button">Yes</button><button id="yes" onclick="circle1.style.fill='red';" type="button">No</button> </span></p>
<span style="color: #FFFFFF;"> </span></details>
```

I've attempted to insert "active" functionality, but I am definitely out of my depth.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My background in HTML is extremely limited -- everything I know has been self-taught in the moment.

Note:  For added context, I am adding html source code to a web content box in Liferay.

Comment: HTML by itself doesn't maintain state across refreshes, you need to store your state and restore it when the page loads. This question as is is too broad and would require that we write code for you instead of showing you what's wrong with your code. Please make an attempt at storing it with JS, if you can't get it to work, then show what you tried and ask a question.